# Groovy script not parsing XML correctly

Tags: java, xml, parsing, groovy

I am trying to use Groovy to parse the following XML:

```
<list>
    <list>
        <widget>
            <fizz id="3" />
            <buzz>false</buzz>
            <explanations/>
        </widget>
        <widget>
            <fizz id="3" />
            <buzz>true</buzz>
            <explanations>
                <string>What is the meaning of life?</string>
                <string>I like the color blue.</string>
            </explanations>
        </widget>
        <widget>
            <fizz id="45" />
            <buzz>true</buzz>
            <explanations>
                <string>I could really go for some pizza right now.</string>
            </explanations>
        </widget>
    </list>
</list>
```

If a `<widget/>` element has a `true` `<buzz/>` child, then it will start aggregating all `explanations/string` children into a master `List<String>`. Thus, given the sample XML above, it would have the following behavior:

1. First `list/list/widget/buzz` is `false`, so don't do anything
2. Second `list/list/widget/buzz` is `true`, so engage *string aggregation* mode:

   1. The second `list/list/widget/explanations` has 2 `<string/>` children; add them both to a master list (`masterList`)
3. Third  `list/list/widget/buzz` is `true`, so continue aggregating its children strings into the master list

   1. The third `list/list/widget/explanations` has 1 `<string/>` child; add it to the master list (`masterList`)
4. The `masterList` now has 3 strings in it: 2 from the 2nd widget, and 1 from the 3rd widget

So far, here's my best attempt:

```
boolean buzzesExist = false;
List<String> masterList = new ArrayList<String>();

use(DOMCategory) {
    element.normalize();

    element.'widget'.each { widget ->
        // If widget/buzz is true, then buzzes exist.
        if(widget.'buzz'.text) {
            buzzesExist = true;
        }

        // If buzzes exist, then aggregate all explanation strings into
        // into "masterList".
        if(buzzesExist) {
            for(String exp : widget.'explanations')
                masterList.add(exp);
    }
}
```

This runs, but causes the `masterList` to contain all sorts of bizarro DOM stuff in it (too large for me to paste in). Can any Groovy gurus spot where I'm goin awrye? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The variable buzzesExist is never going back to false so after the first widget with buzz you will alwazs do the second for

Comment: Good catch but that's OK. Later on in the script I check to see if `buzzesExist` and I do some other stuff with it.

Comment: what are you exactly getting in the masterList?

Comment: Each of the `<string>` values that are in the XML. In the above example, `masterList` would have a size of 3 and would contain the Strings: `What is the meaning of life?`, `I like the color blue.`, and `I could really go for some pizza right now`.

Comment: FYI - i just updated my code to show 1 part of it that I got working. I added `.text` to the end of my `widget.'buzz'` conditional and that seems to be working. But the `masterList` is still wonky and full of DOM fodder.

Comment: But the `masterList` is full of unseful things or the representation of it. if the strings that you get here `for(String exp : job.'explanations')` are those you want, the `masterList` should be filled well. I mean, are you sure that job.'explanations' has what you want?

Comment: Very sorry @iberbeu - that was a typo on my part. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not XmlParser?

**UPDATE**:

```
list = new XmlParser().parseText xml

widgetWithExplanations = list.breadthFirst()
  .findAll { it.buzz.text() == "true" }

masterList = widgetWithExplanations
  .collect { it.explanations.string*.text() }
  .flatten()

assert masterList == [
    "What is the meaning of life?", 
    "I like the color blue.", 
    "I could really go for some pizza right now."]


emptyExplanations = widgetWithExplanations
    .count { !it.explanations.string }

assert emptyExplanations == 0
```

Otherwise your domcategory is probably missing `exp.text()` inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) - two followups: how would I (1) check to see if `explanations` has a size of 0 or not, and save that into a bool, and (2) how would I save explanations into a `List<String>` called `masterList`? Thanks again!

Comment: Updated. Now it counts the how many explanations are empty (variable `emptyExplanations`) and saves the strings in a `masterList` variable

Comment: Thank you again @Will P!!! Last followup, I promise! What package is `XmlParser` stored in? I can't find it in Java 6 or Java 7. What import statements do I need to use to import it into the script and make it available? Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: It is in groovy.util. No need to import it :-). http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/XmlParser.html